# Video does not play on my website. I'm using PHP, HTML for playing uploaded videos also i'm using localhost currently.

Tags: php, html, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41s07.jpg)

I have used the following code for displaying the video. Video container is visible but video is not!

`

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","virtual");

    if(isset($_GET['name'])) {
        $name = $_GET['name'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM video WHERE name = '$name'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

        if(! $result){
                throw new My_Db_Exception('Database error: ' . mysqli_error());
            }

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $name = $row['name'];
            $destination = $row['destination'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            echo '<div class="container">';
            echo "<h2>$name</h2><hr>";
            echo '<video width="804px" height="430px" controls>';
            echo '<source src="http://localhost/virtual2/'.$destination.'">';
            echo "</video>";
            echo "<h4>$description</h4>";
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    ?>`
```

Comment: Try to take the url of video (http://localhost/virtual2/DESTINATION_VAR) to browser and check if it's valid or not

Comment: I assume you forgot to add `$name` variable to your `url`.

Comment: Thanks you soo much Ahmad Rezk for your reply, I tweaked the url stored in the database and now it works properly. But now the problem is mp4 file is playing like a charm but .avi file is not playing. Can you please help!

Comment: Amr Aly, in destination variable I have stored the full path of the file including the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

only way the video wouldn't play is if it can't find the file. best way to test this is echo "http://localhost/virtual2/'.$destination.'" and paste the result into a new browser window to see if the video loads.

Comment: Yes you are right, actually the problem was that I was storing the the wrong path in the database. The path stored in the database was "http://localhost/virtual2/uploads/$file_name" and while displaying the video it was getting appended with the url again like this "http://localhost/virtual2/http://localhost/virtual2/'.$destination.'".' "